# Sitecore Forms starts tracking (analytics) despite explicit consent for tracking has been set true for a site

Tags: xdb, sitecore-forms

**Environment:** `SXA 10x, Azure PaaS`

I have configured the `SXA` site to require explicit tracking consent by adding this setting to site properties `explicitConsentForTrackingIsRequired = "true"`.

The tracking is disabled with this until consent is given however only when I browse or interact with a Sitecore form say updated the Input text field and changed focus I noticed that the tracking has been already started which does not obey the consent manager.

Could someone help let me know if I missed any configuration here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks a bug in sc 10 (seems to be an issue in sc 10.1 as well)

**Details:** Interaction with form fields makes an async post call to `/fieldtracking/register`, by inspecting the *FieldTrackingController*,  you shall notice the *Register* Action method makes an explicit call to `_formEventsTracker.RegisterEvent` (this call is triggered when form fields performance tracking is enabled from forms editor ).

This makes an internal call to `AnalyticsTrackerResolver.CurrentPage` -> Code below

```
public ICurrentPageContext CurrentPage
    {
      get
      {
        if (!Tracker.Enabled)
          return (ICurrentPageContext) null;
        if (Tracker.Current == null)
          AnalyticsTrackerResolver.StartTracking();
        return Tracker.Current?.Session?.Interaction?.CurrentPage;
      }
    }
```

You may notice this is missing a condition check to check whether User Consent has been granted before starting tracking.

**Workaround:**
Yet to to raise a bug with sitecore until then you may have the workaround I have which worked well for me:

Add a custom AnalyticsTrackerResolver (ServiceConfigurator) with following additional check to return null if cannot start tracking until user consent has been given (from Consent Manager)

`!if (!ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConsentManager>().CanStartTracking) return (ICurrentPageContext)null;`

Complete Code:

```
public ICurrentPageContext CurrentPage
        {
            get
            {
                if (!Tracker.Enabled)
                    return (ICurrentPageContext)null;
                if (!if (!ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IConsentManager>().CanStartTracking))
                    return (ICurrentPageContext)null;
                if (Tracker.Current == null)
                    xDbAnalyticsTrackerResolver.StartTracking();
                return Tracker.Current?.Session?.Interaction?.CurrentPage;
            }
        }
```

Comment: For what it's worth, I see the same for non-AJAX form submissions in Sitecore 10.1.2. Also, the above solution doesn't work for non-AJAX forms...